# how to stop calling onclick function while refreshing a page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page with a p:Menuitem using OnClick function.
My problem is that when i refresh the page, the event onclick is still running, how can i stop it?

Client-side code:

```
<p:submenu label="Ordres de Fabrication" styleClass="submenustyle" >
    <p:submenu label="Ordre non Réalisé">
     <p:menuitem value="Afficher" outcome="/admin/gestionduplanning/ofnonrealiseAfficher.xhtml" onclick="#{ofrealiser.getofnonrealiser()}" />
     <p:menuitem value="Ajouter" outcome="/admin/gestionduplanning/ofnorealiseAjouter.xhtml"  />
     </p:submenu> ...
```

**UPDATE 1 :**

```
<p:menuitem value="Afficher" outcome="/admin/gestionduplanning/ofnonrealiseAfficher.xhtml" onclick="#{ofrealiser.getofnonrealiser()}" actionListener="#{exporterPlanningGlobal.refreshfromjsfdateplanning()}" />
```

the managed bean methode :

```
   public void refreshfromjsfdateplanning()
   {
    System.out.println("Test actionlistener");
   }
```

but the methode isnt called because in my IDE glassfish it didnt print anything .

how to get the actionlistner working ??

**UPDATE 2 :**

i found that when i remove the outcome from the menu the action listner is working .. but when i use outcome or url to go to a page didnt work how to solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both onclick and oncomplete should only be used to call a javascript event handler**.

If you want to call something on server when clicking a menu item then use **actionListener**.
As a side line, of course the code inside the onclick will trigger when refreshing the page because the jsf expressions are evaluated on the page rendering phase.

You can find a working example on the [Primefaces Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf)

Comment: can u give me an example to add actionlistener because i use it like this but didnt work : `<p:menuitem value="Exporter tous les plannings" styleClass="submenustyle" outcome="/espaceZP01/gestionduplanning/exporterTousPlanning.xhtml" actionListener="#{exporterPlanningGlobal.refreshfromjsfdateplanning()}"/>`

Comment: Well what does it mean "it won't work"? The method isn't called? Also why don't you use the same method as above, the method called by onclick? Also post some code of that method...

Comment: i found that when i remove the outcome from the menu the action listner is working .. but when i use outcome or url to go to a page didnt work how to solve that ?

Comment: try to do some IDE debugging. Anyway it's odd to use outcome and actionListener together because both are triggered when the menu item is clicked. First try to see if the method is called without the outcome and second, if you really need to do something before navigate to another page then you can do a navigation from the actionListener method. Also you can use url attribute for navigation...

Comment: i tryed a navigation from the actionListener methode like this but didnt work (i deleted the outcome)  `public String refreshfromjsfdateplanning()
   {
     System.out.println("Test action listner");
         return "/espaceZP01/gestionduplanning/exporterTousPlanning.xhtml";
     }`

Comment: it doesn't work because the actionListener must be a void method. For that you use action attribute or do the navigation like this: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);`

Comment: You have to read more about java, jsf and primefaces... read the documentation, books, everything... these are basic stuff and you won't go anywhere without knowing the basics

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem  : do a treatment before navigating with p:menuitem :

```
<p:menuitem value="Exporter tous les plannings" styleClass="submenustyle" action="#{exporterPlanningGlobal.refreshfromjsfdateplanning}" update="@form"/>
```

and managed bean methode :

```
   public String refreshfromjsfdateplanning()
   {
    System.out.println("treatment done"); 
 return "/espaceZP01/gestionduplanning/exporterTousPlanning.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"; 
   }
```

Comment: Yes, by using action... that's what I just said to you!

Comment: Yes spauny just i changed actionlistner to action . thank you for your help .

Comment: @marouanviche really?